# Access Element of Array after Splitting string in a bash script

Tags: bash

In a bash script I split a line into pieces and then again split one of the pieces by "/".

example of my input is:

> line="./function -o=25-32  -f=1000 -t=1000 -r=SNISSWWN
>   /../allfiles/1BE3C_25.pdb >Log.txt"

The code I use is as below:

```
stringarray=($line)
pdb=${stringarray[5]}
echo "The 5th element is: "$pdb

arr=$(echo $pdb | tr "/" "\n")

echo "elements in arr are: "
for x in $arr
do
    echo $x
done

echo "The second element in arr is:"
echo  ${arr[2]}
```

The out put I get is:

> The 5th element is: /../allfiles/1BE3C_25.pdb  elements in arr are: ..
>   allfiles  1BE3C_25.pdb
>
> The second element in arr is:

which means that I can't access the elements in arr.

Can you please tell me how I can access that?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning `arr` as a string, not an array. You're missing a set of parentheses

```
arr=( $(echo $pdb | tr "/" "\n") )
```